# " Laurent expansion" of quasi-periodic complex complex function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, theta-functions, laurent-polynomials

Suppose a complex function $f(z)$ depends only on $z$, and satisfies the quasi-periodicity in both directions:
$$f(z+ a_x)= e^{i \theta_{a_x}} f(z)$$
$$f(z+ i a_y)= e^{i \theta_{a_y}} f(z)$$
where $\theta_{a_x}$ and $\theta_{a_y}$ are  real functions of $a_x$ and $a_y$ respectively. One can expand $f(z)$ using Laurent expansion $\sum_n c_n z^n$, but $z^n$ is not quasi-periodic. My question is: does there exist a basis which respects the quasi-periodicity and can expand arbitrary quasi-periodic complex function?

Comment: I don't think the word quasi-periodic is adapted. The only meromorphic functions such that $f(z+a)=A f(z), f(z+b)=Bf(z)$ for some $a/b\not \in \Bbb{R}$ are the quotients of theta functions ($\theta(z)=\sum_n e^{2i\pi n u z} e^{-\pi n^2 a/b}$ satisfies the same thus $f(z)/\theta(z)$ is doubly periodic, then [construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) a quotient of theta functions having the same zeros/poles)

Answer (score 3):

[Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave#Proof_of_Bloch%27s_theorem) says that $f(z)=e^{iθz/a}u(z)$, with $u(z+a)=u(z)$. Then $u(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \xi^n$ has a series expansion in powers of $\xi=e^{2\pi iz/a}$, which can be seen as a Fourier or Laurent series (see [Laurent series yields Fourier series](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/laurentfourier.pdf)).

Comment: thank you! I agree with your first part of the answer, using the Bloch theorem. However,  I found I formulated the question too sloppy. What I mean is that $f(z)$ is quasi-periodic in both directions on torus. So $\xi= e^{2\pi i z/a}$ is not the transformation I really want (which is periodic only in one direction). I re-edited the question.

Comment: For $z=x+iy$ you have a function $f(x,y)$  on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which satisfies $f(x,y)=e^{i\theta_x x/a_x}e^{i\theta_y y/_y}u(x,y)$ and $u(x,y)=\sum_{m,n}c_{mn}\xi_x^m\xi_y^n$, with $\xi_x=e^{2\pi i x/a_x}$, $\xi_y=e^{2\pi i y/a_y}$.